# How to systematically normalize inequalities to < (lt) and <= (le) in Coq?

Tags: coq

In proving facts about inequalities (for real numbers), there is `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`. It's kind of tedious to write down and use theorems/lemmas for both these forms.

Currently, I am converting these to just `<` and `<=` manually by first `assert` and then proving a trivial subgoal. I was wondering if it is possible to automatically normalize all inequalities to just `<` and `<=` in the hypotheses and the goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gt` and `ge` are functions that call `lt` and `le` respectively on swapped arguments. To get rid of them, just unfold them.

```
unfold gt, ge.
```

You may want to unfold `lt` as well: it's defined in terms of `le`. Since the definition of `gt` uses `lt`, unfold `gt` first.

```
unfold gt, ge, lt.
```

You can tell Coq to try this when attempting to prove a goal with `auto`.

```
Hint Unfold gt ge lt.
```